# Read double data from a text file - differences in read time

Tags: c#, double, string-parsing

Using C# I'm reading data from text files into a 2D list for further processing.  Each file is 256 doubles, space delimited in 256 lines, each line is read into a list of doubles and each list is added to a list of lines. All files have 256x256 = 65,536 data points.

I've got code that reads the files and works well for some files but for others it takes a really long time.  Since all files are formatted in the same way and contain the same number of data points I don't understand the difference in read time, any one got any ideas?

How can I speed up the read time of file 2?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
        private Data ReadData (string name, string file)
        {
            List<List<Double>> data_points = new List<List<Double>>();

            String input = File.ReadAllText( file );

            foreach (string row in input.Split('\n'))
            {
                List<Double> line_list = new List<double>();
                foreach (string col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
                {
                    if(row != "")
                    {
                    line_list.Add(double.Parse(col.Trim()));
                    }

                }
                if(line_list.Count > 1)
                {
                data_points.Add(line_list);
                }
            }

            Data temp_data = new Data(name, data_points);
            return temp_data;
        }
```

Example text files are here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/diindi2qjlgoxep/FOV2_t1.txt?dl=0 => reads fast

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xrgdz0nq24ypz8/FOV2_t2.txt?dl=0 => reads slow

In answer to some of the comments:
@AntDC - What constitutes a valid double? I tried replacing Parse.Double with Convert.ToDouble with no improvement.

@Henk Holterman - the difference in read time is very noticeable <1s for the first file and approx. 50s for the second file. It appears to be repeatable.

@Slai - I moved both files to other locations and it had no impact on read time.  Both files were exported from the same program within seconds of one another.

Comment: Are all thye values valid doubles?
Double.Parse can be slow for invalid doubles.

Comment: Specify "a really long time". With respect to other case. Is this repeatable? How dis you measure, what did you do to eliminate GC and I/O artifacts?

Comment: seems like the file(s) is fragmented, meaning the file is spread on multiple parts of the hard disk instead of just one contiguous area. You can run Disk Defragmenter, or copy the files to a new location.

Comment: I can't reproduce the difference. Both files completed in about 0.1 second in VS 2015 with your code before the `Data` line. Is any of the files in a shared folder, or is there anything related in the `Data` class constructor?

Comment: Slai you are right it isn't the read file part that was the issue it was the Data class constructor that was taking much longer in the second case.  Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: By the way, working code questions are usually a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com (in case you have any trouble with optimizing the `Data` class constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise you can optimize your code, instead reading the whole file and after that splitting it. Just read line by line.

```
List<Double> line_list = new List<double>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt"))
{
    string[] rows = line.Trim().Split(' ');

    foreach(string el in rows)
    {
        line_list.Add(double.Parse(el.Trim()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've found the problem later on in the class constructor but I've also implemented this change to improve performance.